# ¿Como evitar que un texto dentro de un link se rote al usar transform en css?

Tags: html, css3, css-transform

```css
a {
  margin-left: 10%;
  background: rgba(33, 150, 243, .8);
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 5%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  line-height: 29%;
  height: 80px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg) skewY(-5deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-30deg) skewY(-5deg);
  -ms-transform: skew(-30deg) skewY(-5deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-30deg) skewY(-5deg);
  transform: skew(-30deg) skewY(-5deg);
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<a target="_blank" href="#">
  <p class="texto_360">TOUR</p>
  <p><b class="strong_360">360º</b></p>
</a>
```

Verán, tengo esto

```
<a target="_blank" href="#"><p class="texto_360">TOUR</p><p><b class="strong_360">360º</b></p></a>
```

Con este css:

```
.links_360 a {
    background: rgba(33, 150, 243, .8);
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5%;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-right: 1%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    line-height: 29%;
    height: 80px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-30deg) skewY(-5deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-30deg) skewY(-5deg);
    -ms-transform: skew(-30deg) skewY(-5deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-30deg) skewY(-5deg);
    transform: skew(-30deg) skewY(-5deg);
    color: white;
}
```

El .links_360 es un span que contiene los 2 links. el problema es que también el texto se rota, intente aplicar el transform al texto hacia el otro lado pero no funciona.

¿Alguna solución? gracias.

Comment: puedes explicar como deberia funcionar? puedes cargar un snippet o algo asi para ver tu codigo funcionando?

Comment: Usa una capa distinta para el texto, fuera de la que se le aplica el transform.

Comment: @sioesi listo ya puedes verlo, es simplemente que el texto no debe rotarse

Comment: @ArnauCastellví probare eso a ver, gracias

Comment: Agregando skew de 30° a los p vuelven a su estado normal: `p {
  transform: skew(30deg);
}`.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía No entiendo, intente hacerlo hace rato y no funciono, lo intente ahora y si :l claro tuve que modificar esta parte del <a>  transform: skew(-30deg) skewY(-5deg); a skewY(-3); para que se viera bien, pero funciono así que gracias si quieres la pones como respuesta para puntuar como la mejor respuesta jajaja

Comment: De nada. ¿Eliminas tu pregunta o gustas la responda?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía responde para puntuarte, ;)